# Does this c++11 lambda code invoke undefined behavior?

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, language-lawyer, undefined-behavior

C++11 §5.1.2/6

> The closure type for a lambda-expression with no lambda-capture has a [...] conversion function [...]. The value returned by this conversion function shall be the address of a function that, when invoked, has the same effect as invoking the closure type’s function call operator.

Note: this doesn't say that the conversion will always return the *same* value for the same type. So, does the following program run afoul of UB **and** all the meaning destruction that it implies?

```
int main() {
  auto f = []{};
  return ((+f) == (+f));
}
```

Note: I'd be thoroughly surprised if any real compiler were to give anything but `true`, but the question is about if a compiler could *legally* do anything else?

---

Edit:

C++11 §1.3.24

> undefined behavior
>
> behavior for which this International Standard imposes no requirements
>   [ Note: Undefined behavior may be expected when this International Standard omits any explicit definition of behavior or when a program uses an erroneous construct or erroneous data

Comment: Are you sure unary + is allowed for lambdas? Aside from that, your program is well-formed, and only has implementation-defined behavior due to returning 1 from `main()`.

Comment: @Deduplicator: It is allowed. The lambda is implicitly converted to a pointer, and the pointer may have `+` performed on it (`+` is the identity function in this context).

Answer (score 2):

No, it's neither undefined nor unspecified. You don't know ahead of time whether it'll always be the *same* result (`true` or `false`), but there's nothing in that which means your program has undefined behaviour or that the result falls under the definition of an "unspecified value".

Simply put, this is about as UB as a call to `rand()`, or even to `&someVariable`.

Comment: A call to `rand()` is definitely something that I would classify as unspecified: `[defns.unspecified]` "behavior, for a well-formed program construct and correct data, that depends on the implementation".

Comment: @Mankarse: The semantics of `rand()` are not in any way implementation-defined. By your definition of "unspecified", any program that takes input from the system attains unspecified values. Remember that _using_ unspecified values is UB. This is not that. Note how the definition you cite says "behavior", not "value". The behaviour is completely defined by the standard, so it does not apply.

Comment: I never said "unspecified value", nor "implementation defined", I said "unspecified behaviour". These three terms have different meanings, please read what I'm saying before replying.

Comment: And no, user-input is not "unspecified behaviour", because it does not depend on the implementation, but rather on the execution environment (and the... surprise suprise... input from the user).

Comment: You asserted that this behaviour "depends on the implementation". It does not. This is far from rocket science. The language defines precisely what happens when you compare two function pointers, and it defines what happens with those lambdas. There is no scope for the implementation to define semantics. It is _not_ up to the implementation, so it is _not_ unspecified.

Comment: What does it depend on, if not the implementation? The standard does *not* define precisely which particular function pointer will be returned (just the behaviour of dereferencing and calling the resulting function pointer). *This* is where the unspecified behaviour is coming from.

Comment: The _behaviour_ depends on the rules of the language. The OP quoted them. Go read the question. The _value_ depends on fate and the mood of the universe, but that is entirely neither here not there, because no definition you've quoted talks about the value. I ask you again, do you think `&someVariable` is "unspecified behaviour"?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Did you mean using `indeterminate` values? Because `unspecified` values only make the outcome at worst `unspecified`.

Comment: @Deduplicator: Yeah, possibly. It's tangential and doesn't make Mankarse any less wrong, but yeah.

Comment: I never said indeterminate value. I said unspecified behaviour. `&someVariable` does not have unspecified behaviour. Printing `&someVariable`, or casting `&someVariable` to an integral value and comparing it to something, etc... those have unspecified behaviour. If you never do one of those things, your program has behaviour that is completely specified by the standard. If you *do*, then suddenly you have unspecified behaviour.

Comment: Just because it doesn't fall under the definition of "unspecified value", doesn't mean that it doesn't have unspecified behavior.

Comment: @Mankarse: Right, _and this is not unspecified behaviour_. **The standard defines precisely what the behaviour is.** You seem to be under the impression that any program whose _output_ — **values** — that are not calculable at "standard-time", not compile-time and let alone run-time, must have "unspecified behaviour", which is ridiculous.

Answer (score 1):

It is OK to test function pointers (of the same type) for equality, even when they are not equal to each other (otherwise what would be the point of `==` for function pointers).

From `[expr.eq]`:

> Pointers of the same type (after pointer conversions) can be compared for equality. Two pointers of the same type compare equal if and only if they are both null, both point to the same function, or both represent the same address (3.9.2).

There is nothing in your program that has undefined behavior. Your program has unspecified behavior, in that the equality check could return either `true` or `false`, but your program could not summon nasal demons, fire the missiles, wipe your harddrive, or any of the other nasty behaviours associated with undefined behaviour.

Comment: See citation of section 1.3.24 for what's defined as undefined behavior.

Comment: I know what undefined behaviour is... As stated in this answer, your program has *unspecified* behavior, not *undefined* behavior.

Comment: I don't think it's unspecified. It may not always be the same, but that's not what unspecified means. Is the value of `rand()` "unspecified"? Of `getSomeInputFromTheUser()`? No.

Comment: How do you get `+f` comparing to `+f` being unspecified?? How can they be unequal if `f` is a lambda?

Comment: @Deduplicator: Because the standard does not require that the conversion to a function pointer always returns the same function pointer for the same lambda.

Comment: The standard doesn't define it (that I can find) ∴ I think it falls under 1.3.24. I think things are only "unspecified" if they are explicitly unspecified.

Comment: The standard does impose a range of possible behaviours (either the program returns `1`, or it returns `0`, as implied by the definition of unary `+`, lambdas, and the equality operator). If the behaviour were undefined the standard would impose *no* restrictions.

Comment: @BCS: It may be unspecified whether each conversion potentially returns a pointer to a different function, but that doesn't make it UB, only unspecified. (In this context at worst `implementation defined`)

Comment: It still doesn't make the behaviour unspecified. It just makes the value something that is not prescribed by the standard. There is a not-so-subtle difference between these two things.

Comment: `unspecified behaviour` is precisely that behaviour that is not prescribed by the standard (but for which the standard imposes a range of possible behaviours). Reread `[defns.unspecified]`.

Comment: @Mankarse: The behavior is restricted: It must return a pointer to a function [...]. It just does not specify that it must always return a pointer to the *same* function. So, `unspecified` whether it's always the same.

Comment: @Deduplicator: Indeed.